# Как убрать отступ у Bootstrap класса help-block?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Этот код не помогает, как можно исправить? убрать отступ bootstrap класса help-block пиксилей на 5-10. Без поднятия чекбокса.

```
.form-horizontal .help-block {
    padding-bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputСonfirmPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Пароль</label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Пароли не совпадают" placeholder="Confirm" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors">Повторите пароль</div>
        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы в инспекторе туда наводили мышью, отступ точно там где пытаетесь исправить? точно его вам не `form-group` добавляет?

Comment: form-group где по 5px отступ, а вот когда вставляю <div class="help-block with-errors">Повторите</div> то отступ очень большой получается. Вот и подумал, что класс help-block

Comment: приведите в вопросе полный код примера